# Microsoft Visual Studio 2008: devenv.exe ignores /useenv option

Tags: visual-studio-2008, environment-variables, devenv

in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008, I want to set C++ directories (includes, libraries, etc.) for a solution (*.sln) from command line.  Until Visual Studio 2003, I've successfully relied upon /useenv option of devenv.exe, started from command line.  This does not seem to work on Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition.  Directories set by environment variables INCLUDE and LIB are being ignored.

Only reference I've found for this issue is [here](http://chrisoldwood.blogspot.com/2009/06/visual-c-include-variable-and-useenv.html). It mentions an "External Dependencies" section in: Tools -> Options -> Projects & Solutions -> VC++ Directories.  I cannot find such section.  I've found what I think is an "External Dependencies" (I'm not sure because I'm running a VS2008 translated to Italian) section in: right click on solution ! Properties ! Shared Properties? ! External Dependencies?, but such section is empty.

I'm running Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Version 9.0.21022.8 RTM and here's the batch

```
set INCLUDE=C:\Programmi\Microsoft Platform SDK February 2003\Include;C:\Programmi\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003\VC7\ATLMFC\INCLUDE
start "devenv.exe" "mySolution.sln" /useenv
```

"BuildLog.htm" shows this instead:

```
INCLUDE=C:\boost_1_44_0;C:\Programmi\Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional\VC\include;C:\Programmi\Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional\VC\atlmfc\include
```

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I can assure you that the /useenv switch does still work. I can still build all my solutions from the command line, right up to VS2010, with and without STLport (my main reason for overriding the INCLUDE and LIB paths in the first place).

My builds scripts are available here - http://www.cix.co.uk/~gort/win32.htm#scripts

Comment: Thank you for answering.  Currently I'm not working with Visual Studio, thus I can't check out your scripts.